# How to create a loop in Access 2013 VBA to change theme

Tags: database, loops, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am converting databases from .mdb to .accdb. In order to utilize the themes in Access 2013, I need to find a way to loop through all the controls on a form and set the theme. How would I perform this loop?

Answer (score 0):

Looping through controls on a form can be done like this:

```
dim ctl as control

for each ctl in me.controls
    'Do things
    ctl.tag="example"
next ctl
```

Comment: What will I have to do to bring in the Themes coding into the loop?

Comment: The theme is a database-wide setting, not per control. You can change the various formatting options of a control in the loop, using theme colour variables however.

Comment: When you say formatting options, could you give some examples?

Comment: Formatting options such as back colour, border thickness, font, etc.